# Combine Separate Date and Time Columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database I'm working with where the morons that designed the front end software deemed it necessary to create a separate Date and Time field however leaving the Date columns a DATETIME column and the Time as a VARCHAR column.

Essentially my Date and Time looks like this:

Date                       |        Time

2007-10-06 00:00:00.000    |      1135

Instead of just combining the 2 under 1 column as a proper datetime.

I am trying to combine the 2 together so I can acheive exactly this, a proper DATETIME field that combines both sets of information into i.e.

2007-10-06 11:35:00.000

This bit I am struggling with.

I thought I could get away with

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
DECLARE @time VARCHAR

SET @date = '2007-10-06 00:00:00.000'
SET @time = '1125'

SELECT TOP 1
    @date + ( SUBSTRING(@time , 1 , 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@time , 2 , 2)
              + ':00' )
```

Unfortunately not, now I think I am overthinking the problem and just bumping into wall after wall.

Can anyone assist in this matter and point out to me where I am going wrong :/

Comment: Replace final query with this : `SELECT @date + ( SUBSTRING(@time , 1 , 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@time , 3 , 2) + ':00' )`.

Comment: @KarthikDV - Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. :/

Comment: @Lynchie, I have tested that sample!. see the complete code here: `DECLARE @date DATETIME
DECLARE @time VARCHAR(4)

SET @date = '2007-10-06 00:00:00.000'
SET @time = '1125'

SELECT @date + ( SUBSTRING(@time , 1 , 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@time , 3 , 2) + ':00' )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a size for varchar variable `@time`. The default is 1.

You also need to change the second substring to `3,2`.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
DECLARE @time VARCHAR(4)

SET @date = '2007-10-06 00:00:00.000'
SET @time = '1125'

SELECT TOP 1
    @date + ( SUBSTRING(@time , 1 , 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@time , 3 , 2)
              + ':00' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how i would write it

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2007-10-06T00:00:00'
DECLARE @time VARCHAR(4) = '1125'

SELECT @date + stuff(@time, 3,0, ':')
```